# List of Winners of Each World champions Trophy

Tags: sql, apache-spark, pyspark

Total Result of all rounds of Tournament for that player is considered as that player's Score/Result.

Schema:

```
 |-- game_id: string (nullable = true)
 |-- game_order: integer (nullable = true)
 |-- event: string (nullable = true)
 |-- site: string (nullable = true)
 |-- date_played: string (nullable = true)
 |-- round: double (nullable = true)
 |-- white: string (nullable = true)
 |-- black: string (nullable = true)
 |-- result: string (nullable = true)
 |-- white_elo: integer (nullable = true)
 |-- black_elo: integer (nullable = true)
 |-- white_title: string (nullable = true)
 |-- black_title: string (nullable = true)
 |-- winner: string (nullable = true)
 |-- winner_elo: integer (nullable = true)
 |-- loser: string (nullable = true)
 |-- loser_elo: integer (nullable = true)
 |-- winner_loser_elo_diff: integer (nullable = true)
 |-- eco: string (nullable = true)
 |-- date_created: string (nullable = true)
 |-- tournament_name: string (nullable = true)
```

Sample DaraFrame:

```
+--------------------+----------+--------+----------+-----------+-----+----------------+----------------+-------+---------+---------+-----------+-----------+---------+----------+----------------+---------+---------------------+---+--------------------+---------------+
|             game_id|game_order|   event|      site|date_played|round|           white|           black| result|white_elo|black_elo|white_title|black_title|   winner|winner_elo|           loser|loser_elo|winner_loser_elo_diff|eco|        date_created|tournament_name|
+--------------------+----------+--------+----------+-----------+-----+----------------+----------------+-------+---------+---------+-----------+-----------+---------+----------+----------------+---------+---------------------+---+--------------------+---------------+
|86e0b7f5-7b94-4ae...|         1|WCh 2021| Dubai UAE| 2021.11.26|  1.0|Nepomniachtchi,I|       Carlsen,M|1/2-1/2|     2782|     2855|       null|       null|     draw|      null|            draw|     null|                    0|C88|2022-07-22T22:33:...| WorldChamp2021|
|dc4a10ab-54cf-49d...|         2|WCh 2021| Dubai UAE| 2021.11.27|  2.0|       Carlsen,M|Nepomniachtchi,I|1/2-1/2|     2855|     2782|       null|       null|     draw|      null|            draw|     null|                    0|E06|2022-07-22T22:33:...| WorldChamp2021|
|f042ca37-8899-488...|         3|WCh 2021| Dubai UAE| 2021.11.28|  3.0|Nepomniachtchi,I|       Carlsen,M|1/2-1/2|     2782|     2855|       null|       null|     draw|      null|            draw|     null|                    0|C88|2022-07-22T22:33:...| WorldChamp2021|
|f70e4bbc-21e3-46f...|         4|WCh 2021| Dubai UAE| 2021.11.30|  4.0|       Carlsen,M|Nepomniachtchi,I|1/2-1/2|     2855|     2782|       null|       null|     draw|      null|            draw|     null|                    0|C42|2022-07-22T22:33:...| WorldChamp2021|
|c941c323-308a-4c8...|         5|WCh 2021| Dubai UAE| 2021.12.01|  5.0|Nepomniachtchi,I|       Carlsen,M|1/2-1/2|     2782|     2855|       null|       null|     draw|      null|            draw|     null|                    0|C88|2022-07-22T22:33:...| WorldChamp2021|
|58e83255-93bb-4d5...|         6|WCh 2021| Dubai UAE| 2021.12.03|  6.0|       Carlsen,M|Nepomniachtchi,I|    1-0|     2855|     2782|       null|       null|Carlsen,M|      2855|Nepomniachtchi,I|     2782|                   73|D02|2022-07-22T22:33:...| WorldChamp2021|
|29181d93-73f4-4fb...|         7|WCh 2021| Dubai UAE| 2021.12.04|  7.0|Nepomniachtchi,I|       Carlsen,M|1/2-1/2|     2782|     2855|       null|       null|     draw|      null|            draw|     null|                    0|C88|2022-07-22T22:33:...| WorldChamp2021|
|8a4ccd8c-d437-429...|         8|WCh 2021| Dubai UAE| 2021.12.05|  8.0|       Carlsen,M|Nepomniachtchi,I|    1-0|     2855|     2782|       null|       null|Carlsen,M|      2855|Nepomniachtchi,I|     2782|                   73|C43|2022-07-22T22:33:...| WorldChamp2021|
|55a122db-27d1-495...|         9|WCh 2021| Dubai UAE| 2021.12.07|  9.0|Nepomniachtchi,I|       Carlsen,M|    0-1|     2782|     2855|       null|       null|Carlsen,M|      2855|Nepomniachtchi,I|     2782|                   73|A13|2022-07-22T22:33:...| WorldChamp2021|
|1f900d18-5ea3-4f4...|        10|WCh 2021| Dubai UAE| 2021.12.08| 10.0|       Carlsen,M|Nepomniachtchi,I|1/2-1/2|     2855|     2782|       null|       null|     draw|      null|            draw|     null|                    0|C42|2022-07-22T22:33:...| WorldChamp2021|
```

My code looks like this. I think it's messed up. Am I supposed to do sum somewhere?

```
winners = df_history_info.filter(df_history_info['winner'] != "draw").groupBy("tournament_name").agg({"winner":"max"}).show()
```

I'm getting this result but it is incorrect in many cases.

```
+---------------+--------------------+
|tournament_name|         max(winner)|
+---------------+--------------------+
| WorldChamp2004|              Leko,P|
| WorldChamp1894|   Steinitz, William|
| WorldChamp2013|     Carlsen, Magnus|
|  FideChamp2000|       Yermolinsky,A|
| WorldChamp2007|           Svidler,P|
|  FideChamp1993|       Timman, Jan H|
|WorldChamp1910b|     Lasker, Emanuel|
| WorldChamp1921|Capablanca, Jose ...|
| WorldChamp1958|    Smyslov, Vassily|
| WorldChamp1981|  Kortschnoj, Viktor|
| WorldChamp1961|         Tal, Mihail|
| WorldChamp1978|  Kortschnoj, Viktor|
| WorldChamp1960|         Tal, Mihail|
| WorldChamp1948|    Smyslov, Vassily|
| WorldChamp1929|    Bogoljubow, Efim|
| WorldChamp1934|    Bogoljubow, Efim|
| WorldChamp1986|      Kasparov, Gary|
|   PCAChamp1995|      Kasparov, Gary|
| WorldChamp1886|Zukertort, Johann...|
| WorldChamp1907|     Lasker, Emanuel|
+---------------+--------------------+
```

Comment: can you provide a sample of your pyspark dataframe? it would be helpful to see what some of the column values look like (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48427185/how-to-make-good-reproducible-apache-spark-examples)).

Comment: @DerekO I have added the sample dataframe. I'll take a look at your answer and see if I can fix it. Thank you!

Comment: thanks for the update! so the `winner` column contains a string that says either `"draw"` or the name of the winning player. in that case, i think my answer should work as it gets the max count of the winner when grouping by `tournament_name`

Comment: Thanks! It worked. I grouped and then filtered the draws and used the WindowSpec @DerekO

Comment: glad to hear my answer helped, @AutumnRain !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the `winner` column contains either the winning player's name  or the word `"draw"` which you've filtered out, then this means the operation `.agg({"winner":"max"})` will return the max of a string. This is why `Zukertort, Johann...` appears as the winner of `WorldChamp1886` instead of `Steinitz...`, and `Yermolinksky,A` appears as in the winner in the 128 person field in the `FideChamp2000`.

Here is an example of something you could try with a spark dataframe that looks like the following:

```
df = spark.createDataFrame(
    [
        ("WC1", "A"),
        ("WC1", "B"),
        ("WC1", "A"),
        ("WC1", "A"),
        ("WC1", "A"),
        ("WC1", "B"),
        ("WC1", "A"),
        ("WC1", "B"),
        ("WC2", "F"),
        ("WC2", "F"),
        ("WC2", "F"),
        ("WC2", "D"),
        ("WC2", "D"),
        ("WC2", "E"),
        ("WC2", "F"),
        ("WC2", "F"),
    ],
    ["tournament_name", "winner"]  # add your column names here
)
```

And you have a situation like this where you want to determine who wins each tournament by the most number of times their name appears in the winner column.

```
+---------------+------+
|tournament_name|winner|
+---------------+------+
|            WC1|     A|
|            WC1|     B|
|            WC1|     A|
|            WC1|     A|
|            WC1|     A|
|            WC1|     B|
|            WC1|     A|
|            WC1|     B|
|            WC2|     F|
|            WC2|     F|
|            WC2|     F|
|            WC2|     D|
|            WC2|     D|
|            WC2|     E|
|            WC2|     F|
|            WC2|     F|
+---------------+------+
```

You can do a groupby count on `tournament_name` and `winner`:

```
d = df.groupby(["tournament_name","winner"]).count()
```

And that gives you this pyspark dataframe:

```
+---------------+------+-----+
|tournament_name|winner|count|
+---------------+------+-----+
|            WC1|     B|    3|
|            WC1|     A|    5|
|            WC2|     F|    5|
|            WC2|     D|    2|
|            WC2|     E|    1|
+---------------+------+-----+
```

Then following [this example](https://sparkbyexamples.com/pyspark/pyspark-find-maximum-row-per-group-in-dataframe/), you could create a `WindowSpec` object that partitions by `tournament_name`, and sorts by in descending order of the `count` column, and apply it to d:

```
from pyspark.sql.window import Window
from pyspark.sql.functions import col, row_number

windowDept = Window.partitionBy("tournament_name").orderBy(col("count").desc())
d.withColumn("row",row_number().over(windowDept)) \
  .filter(col("row") == 1).drop("row") \
  .show()
```

Final result:

```
+---------------+------+-----+
|tournament_name|winner|count|
+---------------+------+-----+
|            WC1|     A|    5|
|            WC2|     F|    5|
+---------------+------+-----+
```